# Error in authentication in pubnub

Tags: android, authentication, pubnub

I am using this code for authentication:

```
if (mPubnub == null) {
// publish key left blank as publish event is happening server side           
       mPubnub = new Pubnub("", SUBSCRIBERKEY);
       mPubnub.setCacheBusting(false);
       String authToken = ChatUtils.getMD5HashKey(jsondata.getString(SESSIONTOKEN));
       mPubnub.setAuthKey(authToken);

       mPubnub.setUUID(ChatConstant.CHANNELID);
       mPubnub.isResumeOnReconnect();
       mPubnub.subscribe(ChatConstant.CHANNELID, pubnubConnectionCallback);
   }
```

and getting error:

```
ERROR on channel 54013eec6eb2361f058b4567 : [Error: 112-0] : Authentication Failure. Incorrect Authentication Key : {"channels":["54013eec6eb2361f058b4567"]} : Forbiddencallback_messagemk----> Bundle[{message=SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel 54013eec6eb2361f058b4567 : [Error: 112-0] : Authentication Failure. Incorrect Authentication Key : {"channels":["54013eec6eb2361f058b4567"]} : Forbidden}]
```

Comment: Hi Rahul- as this will involve us seeing your secret key, please contact us at support@pubnub.com and we'll assist you in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and manage to solve this problem. Please find answer below:

1. You have to use same auth key to subscribe from cell phone to a channel.
2. You have to use same auth key to subscribe from server to a channel
3. You have to use same auth key while Granting access from PAM manager to some channel. Won't work if you missed granting permissions from PAM manager
4. You have to check for read and write permissions checkbox on the right hand side of PAM manager.

Thank
Surinder